# Unable to import Excel to database

Tags: python, django

I have a system whereby it allows to import the student attendance file into the system. However, it did not import it successfully. I tried to debug and i found out that when it goes to the importer.py function, it does not go to the  "def _do_save(self, row)", hence that is the problem why it was not saved into database.

importer.py

```
class AttendanceImporter(CsvImporter):

    field_names=["username", "mark"]

    #it does not go to the method.
    def _handle_row(self,row):
        print("this")
        if (not self._is_row_valid(row)):
            return self._FAILED


        username=row["username"]
        if (self._is_username_exist(username)):
            if (self._is_mark_exist(username)):
                if (self._do_update(row)):
                    return self._UPDATED
                else:
                    return self._FAILED
            else:
                if (self._do_save(row)):
                    return self._CREATED
                else:
                    return self._FAILED
        else:
            return self._FAILED

    def _is_row_valid(self, row):
        for item in self.field_names:
            if (len(row[item])==0):
                return False
        return True

    def _is_username_exist(self, username):
        return len(User.objects.filter(username=username))>0
        print(username)

    def _is_mark_exist(self, username):
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        return len(Attendance.objects.filter(user=user))>0
        print(username)

    def _do_save(self, row):
        # create attendace mark
        try:
            attendance=Attendance()
            user=User.objects.get(username=row["username"])
            attendance=Attendance.objects.create(user=user, mark=row["mark"])
            print("save?")
            attendance.save()
        except:
            return False

        return True

    def _do_update(self, row):
        # update attendance mark
        try:
            user=User.objects.get(username=row["username"])
            attendance=Attendance.objects.get(user=user)
            attendance.mark = row["mark"]
            attendance.save()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False

        return True
```

Views.py

```
@transaction.atomic
@csrf_exempt
def data_import(request, file_type):


# TODO: currently only support importing users, later can support importing groups
fields_required = None
if(file_type == "user"):
    fields_required = "username, password, email, matric_number, fullname, groups"
elif (file_type == "attendance"):
    fields_required = "username, mark"


if request.FILES:
    successful = False
    try:
        im = None
        if(file_type == "user"):
            upload_file = request.FILES['user_file']
            file_path = save_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'], filename=generate_unique_file_name(extension="csv"),
                                       filedir=USER_DATA_UPLOAD_PATH)
            im = StudentImporter(source=open(file_path))
        elif (file_type == "attendance"):
            upload_file = request.FILES['attendance_file']

            file_path = save_uploaded_file(upload_file, filename=generate_unique_file_name(extension="csv"),
                                            filedir=USER_DATA_UPLOAD_PATH)

            im = AttendanceImporter(source=open(file_path))

        successful, result = im.import_to_database()

    except Exception:
        pass
    if successful:
        messages.info(request, "The import is successful!\n" + result)
    else:
        messages.warning(request, "The import is NOT successful, no data is imported!")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("student_user_profile_list"))
return render(request,
              "app-appglobal/import-data.html",
              {'type': file_type, 'fields_required': fields_required})
```

Model.py:

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mark=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        ordering=['user']
    def get_mark(self):
        return self.mark
```

Urls

```
   url(r'^student/attendance/$' ,views.data_import,{'file_type':'attendance'},name='attendance_import'),
```

CSVIMPORTER

```
class CsvImporter(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):
def __init__(self, source):
    """
    :param source: a file object
    :return:
    """
    self.source=source

def import_to_database(self):
    """
    :return: (successful:boolean,result:string)
    """
    pass
```

example:

[image]
[image]

Comment: "when it goes to the importer.py function, it only run the first code and did not go to the other part."  What does this mean? There are 6 functions defined in `importer.py`, and none of them are directly referenced by your other code

Comment: It does not go to "def _do_save(self, row):" function, hence it was not successfully inserted into the database. Im not sure what am i missing in the code. @HymnsForDisco

Comment: "It does not go to 'def _do_save(self, row):' function". Again this is still pretty unclear.  The `_do_save` function is not being called? Are you expecting it to be called? Under what conditions?  That function is only called in one place in your code, but it is preceded by a lot of flow control (`if` `else`), you probably need to trace through the code and confirm that each of those conditions is actually correct

Comment: if the file type is attendance then it will go to the elif stmt under data_import. im = AttendanceImporter(source=open(file_path)) will trigger the attendanceimporter. However, def _do_save(self,row) is not triggered when the user clicks submit..

Comment: Calling `AttendanceImporter(...)` will create a new instance of the `AttendanceImporter` class.  There's no indication that any of the functions you have defined in `importer.py` would ever be called, unless they are specially named methods used by the `CsvImporter` class, but there is no information here about the `CsvImporter` class, what module it comes from, or what it does.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It seems that people are getting lost in the code. Bare `except:` statements and `except Exception` are bad practice.

Comment: uploaded the csvimporter and the GUI.